# Senders image for UIControlStateNormal

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton, sender

tl;dr: I'm creating a UIImageView that has the same image as the sender. Im trying to figure out how to go about doing this.

Im trying to get the senders image. Here is my code to get the sender:

```
UIButton *playSelectionTag = (UIButton *)sender;



 if (playSelectionTag.tag == 5) {

    /*
    [popInToolbar release];

    [all release];
    [world release];
    [politics release];
    [TVMovies release];
    [aboutText release];
    [aboutTrueFalse release];
    [scoreText release];

    [spaceBar release];
    [done release];
    */

    popUpPlay = [[UIImageView alloc]init];

    popUpPlay.frame = CGRectMake(playSelectionTag.frame.origin.x, playSelectionTag.frame.origin.x, playSelectionTag.frame.size.width, playSelectionTag.frame.size.height);

    [popUpPlay setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", playSelectionTag.imageView.image]]];

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imageView for UIButton is UIImageView. and image in UIImageView is UIImage.
So converting it in string will not work.

One possible way is use [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage: [playSelectionTag.imageView.image CGImage]]

if it doesn't work then try following.

Keep track of images you used in button. You can achieve this by keeping array of images and storing name of image at same index as playSelectionTag.tag.

Comment: Well that didnt work, i'll just go ahead and create the array and use it like that. Thanks :)

Comment: [UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage is proper constructor. Give this some time because it will give you a lot of flexibility in code.

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
[popUpPlay setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", playSelectionTag.imageView.image]]];
```

With:

```
popUpPlay.image = [playSelectionTag imageForState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Solution you accepted will give you the image of sender in highlighted state.